# iOS/Mac Developer Program, paid apps contract dilemma

Tags: ios, macos, iphone-developer-program

I'm looking to apply for the Individual Mac/iOS developer program, and I've some questions about the paid app contract.

I don't know exactly what needs to be done since I haven't apply for it yet, but I do know I will need to fill in some forms to sell apps on the app store.

And I have a feeling that this will become more complicated by the fact I'm an overseas student in the UK (my home country is neither UK nor US), and I don't currently have a work permit in the UK.

If this can be proven infeasible, I may avoid wasting a $99 subscription fee.

Comment: I was under the impression that you filled in all of your personal info and you tell it where to send the check to.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the apple developer program not programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more a legal matter than technical so I suggest you talk to someone qualified to give you advice.

First, there is the matter of working in the UK. If you are an EU citizen you have no problem otherwise you may need a work permit. Talk to a guidance councillor about this. In your case you will be self-employed so I'm not sure if you really need a work permit. You may have to register your income and pay taxes.

On Apple's part, their main legal obligation in this matter is to pay you and monitor your app to prevent fraud (they'll also monitor your app to see if they need to ban it based on a random number of unknown parameters but that's besides the point). In order to pay you they need to know and comply with laws of your place of residence. In your case the UK. Your citizenship status doesn't matter as long as it is legal for you to work there.

Comment: Thank you! I guess the surest way is to apply from my home country.